# Add control to a panel with autoscroll (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, scroll, controls, addition

I've a panel with property `AutoScroll` = `true`.
By adding other controls dynamically to the panel without scrolling - all works fine!

```
void addControl(){
    int top = 13 + ( this.Controls.Count * cmdSet.Height );
    ucCommandSet cmdSet = new ucCommandSet() { Top = top };
    this.Controls.Add( cmdSet );
}
```

But, if the scrollbar is inserted in a different position than TOP [0],  the controls are  added much further down.

What property do I need to include in the calculation?

regards raiserle

---

Solution by @LarsTech:

```
void addControl(){
    int top = 13 + ( this.Controls.Count * cmdSet.Height ) + this.AutoScrollPosition.Y;
    ucCommandSet cmdSet = new ucCommandSet() { Top = top };
    this.Controls.Add( cmdSet );
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is `ucCommandSet` ? Also, what do you mean by TOP[0] ?

Comment: I mean, the scrollbar is on the TOP (Scrollvalue = 0)

Comment: Sorry, ucCommand is an Usercontrol ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to compensate for the scroll position:

```
{ Top = top + this.AutoScrollPosition.Y };
```

A FlowLayoutPanel does this for you, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. I' searched under Scrollbar.... not Auto.... ****arg****. Big tahnks! regards raiserle

Comment: in my case it was panel.VerticalScroll.Value (note we're asking about the panel, not the UC)