# Autoscroll affects on coordinates when I add a new widget in my Panel widget dynamically. WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll

I faced to an unexpected problem with adding a new widget into main Panel in my WinForms project. I wrote my own class that describes a custom panel that finally is integrated in the first one and is placed on Y coordinate equalled to (Bottom + 2) of the other. This place I have in my static variable. Everything works fine and as I expected. When I click Bottom +, my panel appeares on the first one (Picture 1).
[Everything is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjbUm.png)
But, If I click my Button + so that a ScrollLine could appear, I move it down and click my Button + again. The next Panel is placed not just (Bottom + 2) as it was planned, but it adds some pixels depends on how far is the ScrollButton from its neutral spot. Picture(2)
[This space between my Panels is getting bigger than far than I move the scrollButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auWav.png)

my class Code

```
internal class AddPanel
    {
        const int coordX = 3;
        static int coordY = 4;
        static int num;

        TextBox TBnum, TBquest, TBansw; // for each textbox from our panel
        Panel newPanel; // the panel proper

        public AddPanel(Panel MainPanel, params Button[] buttons)
        {
            newPanel = new Panel();
            TBnum = new TextBox();
            TBquest = new TextBox();
            TBansw = new TextBox();

            newPanel.Location = new Point(coordX, coordY); //TODO: Change coords
            newPanel.Size = new Size(350, 88);
            newPanel.Name = "MyPanel" + Convert.ToString(num);

            TBnum.Location = new Point(3, 3);
            TBnum.Name = "MyTBNum" + Convert.ToString(num);
            TBnum.Size = new Size(27, 23);

            TBquest.Location = new Point(50, 3);
            TBquest.Name = "MyTBquest" + Convert.ToString(num);
            TBquest.Size = new Size(287, 23);

            TBansw.Location = new Point(50, 32);
            TBansw.Name = "MyTBansw" + Convert.ToString(num);
            TBansw.Multiline = true;
            TBansw.Size = new Size(287, 47);


            if (num == 0)
            {
                TBnum.PlaceholderText = "1";
                TBquest.PlaceholderText = "Вопрос. Напр: Адрес приемной комиссии?";
                TBansw.PlaceholderText = "Ответ на вопрос";

            }
            else TBnum.Text = Convert.ToString(num + 1);

            //foreach (Button btn in buttons)
                //btn.Location = new Point(btn.Location.X, btn.Location.Y + 100);

            newPanel.Controls.Add(TBnum);
            newPanel.Controls.Add(TBquest);
            newPanel.Controls.Add(TBansw);
            newPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            MainPanel.Controls.Add(newPanel);

            coordY = newPanel.Bottom + 2 ;
            num++;

        }

        static AddPanel()
        {
            num = 0;
        }
    }
```

Button code:

```
new AddPanel(MainScrollPanel, UpButton, DownButton);
```

How can I manage this problem. I tried to Google, but I found nothing.

Comment: You should be using a UserControl for adding that panel.  The parent container looks like it should be a FlowLayoutPanel instead, which would handle the child control positioning.  Otherwise, see [Add control to a panel with autoscroll (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26262778/719186) for offsetting the scroll position to avoid that gap.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks. I've already solved the problem putting the Scroll button at the initial position before create a new panel. In my case this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
MainScrollPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
```

We can move the ScrollLine to neutral position before we create a new Panel.